# Style ngBootstrap tooltip

Tags: css, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I have a simple ngBootstrap tooltip in an angular 4 component which I'm trying to style.  According to other SO questions this should work:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #00acd6 !important;
    /*!important is not necessary if you place custom.css at the end of your css calls. For the purpose of this demo, it seems to be required in SO snippet*/
    color: #fff;
}
```

but it has no effect.  I confirmed the tooltip-inner class is used inside the tooltip but it's not being applied

Answer (score 4):

I guess that didn't work for you cause you didn't try it on your main style.scss file, (or any other .scss file you load globally via the "styles":[] at angular-cli.json). on the component.scss level it won't work.

I just used:

```
.tooltip-inner {
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
}
```

I think going for: /deep/ isn't a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

[This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JDxw5SCegXxANykrW10B?p=preview) shows how you can style ng-bootstrap tooltips. The key is to use `/deep/` or `::ng-deep`**  to force the style into the child component:

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #00acd6;
    color: #fff;
}
```

By default, Angular uses Emulated [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) which means styles will not propagate from a parent to a child component unless you tell them to (e.g. using `::ng-deep`).

** `/deep/` was [deprecated in Angular 4.3.0](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) and `::ng-deep` is now preferred, although according to the link this will also be deprecated in the future

Comment: These are depricated because they are bad practice and will quickly cause issues across your app when one change effects other components in ways you didn't predict. Changing the main theme as @liron_hazan surgested is a much safer practice.